# Format dot or comma depend on location

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with Vba-excel to import the csv file to excel. I'm stuck with the formatpercent in VBA. if my region is set on US default, it works correctly. However, if any regions use comma for decimal, it does not work correctly anymore.

```
    fuction formatPercentValue (value as string) as string //value = 1
    formatPercentValue = formatPercent(Round(CDbl(Val(value)), 5), 6) 
    // US: 100.000000%, HU (Hungary): 100,000000%
```

when I call that

```
r as range
r.value = formatPercentValue (value) 
// US: r.value = 1, HU: r.value = 1000000
```

I don't know how to fix that because when it appears in excel `US: 100%`
`HU: 100000000%`. I don't know why when r.value can set `1` in US but it is not in HU.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Application.International` to test settings and apply a different formatting :

```
If Application.International(xlCountrySetting) <> 1 Then

If Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) <> "." Then
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213833

Comment: Hi. After checking the `decimalSeparator`, how can we know to set for the return `r.value`? I really don't know to get the right number when set `r.value`

Comment: Could you provide your code : formatPercent as this part of your process, let me know when you've done it, I'll see what I can do! ;)

Comment: Do you know why the method `r.value` get the different value in `dot` and `comma` seperator? My post code is the main code. I try to debug and I got the different values which I mark `//`

Comment: If you don't want the separator to change, use `r.Value2` (value without formatting). And in the line `formatPercentValue = formatPercent(Round(CDbl(Val(value)), 5), 6)`, you use `formatPercent`, could you add that part?

Comment: Hi R3uK. I found the solution for this. I have to replace all comma to a dot. Thank you for your help.